# What are the components of the raw block shown in this image?

Tags: block, block-header

[image]

I'm wondering what the portion between the block header and the transaction data (the un-annotated section) is. I can't seem to find any information on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The diagram is wrong

The data in the gap between the two brackets is the count of transactions and most of the first coinbase transaction.

The start/top of the second bracket is positioned incorrectly.

---

### Various components of a raw block

The image is of bitcoin block 170 with Block ID `00000000d1145790a8694403d4063f323d499e655c83426834d4ce2f8dd4a2ee`

The block header is, as your image shows,
`0100000055bd840a` `78798ad0da853f68` `974f3d183e2bd1db` `6a842c1feecf222a` `00000000ff104ccb` `05421ab93e63f8c3` `ce5c2c2e9dbb37de` `2764b3a3175c8166` `562cac7d51b96a49` `ffff001d283e9e70`

Which can be [explained](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#block) as

| hex data | meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `01000000` | version=1 |
| `55bd840a78798ad0` `da853f68974f3d18` `3e2bd1db6a842c1f` `eecf222a00000000` | hash of prior block (i.e. ID of prior block) |
| `ff104ccb05421ab9` `3e63f8c3ce5c2c2e` `9dbb37de2764b3a3` `175c8166562cac7d` | merkle root |
| `51b96a49` | timestamp |
| `ffff001d` | bits (target) |
| `283e9e70` | nonce |

the `02` following the header tells us the block contains two transactions

The first is the coinbase transaction with TXID `b1fea52486ce0c62bb442b530a3f0132b826c74e473d1f2c220bfa78111c5082`

Its raw data is
`0100000001000000` `0000000000000000` `0000000000000000` `0000000000000000` `0000000000ffffff` `ff0704ffff001d01` `02ffffffff0100f2` `052a010000004341` `04d46c4968bde028` `99d2aa0963367c7a` `6ce34eec332b32e4` `2e5f3407e052d64a` `c625da6f0718e7b3` `02140434bd725706` `957c092db53805b8` `21a85b23a7ac6172` `5bac00000000`

The second is a transaction with TXID
`f4184fc596403b9d638783cf57adfe4c75c605f6356fbc91338530e9831e9e16`

Its raw data is
`0100000001c997a5` `e56e104102fa209c` `6a852dd90660a20b` `2d9c352423edce25` `857fcd3704000000` `004847304402204e` `45e16932b8af5149` `61a1d3a1a25fdf3f` `4f7732e9d624c6c6` `1548ab5fb8cd4102` `20181522ec8eca07` `de4860a4acdd1290` `9d831cc56cbbac46` `22082221a8768d1d` `0901ffffffff0200` `ca9a3b0000000043` `4104ae1a62fe09c5` `f51b13905f07f06b` `99a2f7159b2225f3` `74cd378d71302fa2` `8414e7aab37397f5` `54a7df5f142c21c1` `b7303b8a0626f1ba` `ded5c72a704f7e6c` `d84cac00286bee00` `00000043410411db` `93e1dcdb8a016b49` `840f8c53bc1eb68a` `382e97b1482ecad7` `b148a6909a5cb2e0` `eaddfb84ccf97444` `64f82e160bfa9b8b` `64f9d4c03f999b86` `43f656b412a3ac00` `000000`

The components of the specific transaction hex above are explained in detail in the first link below.

---

Related:

- [In what format does a block store the transaction data?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/113631/13866)
- [What are the parts of a Bitcoin transaction in segwit format?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/113697/13866)