# Are transactions included in a block or is only the Merkle-root hash included in a block

Tags: transactions, blockchain, block

Before broadcasting block into bitcoin blockchain, Does a Block transactions are included in a block or only the hash of them are included in a block. While I am surfing through net, I came across two images which are very ambiguity because in picture-1 transactions are out of block and in picture-2 transactions are included in block and the images are as shown below:

**Picture -1:**
[image: 1]

**Picture -2**

[image: 2]

Answer (score 2):

> in picture-1 transactions are out of block and in picture-2 transactions are included in block

In your picture-1, the transactions are **NOT** shown as outside the block. They are shown as outside the *"block header"*

Your picture-1 has the caption "Simplified Bitcoin Block Chain". You should take care not to interpret a simplified diagram as if it were completely accurate. The second diagram is also simplified and not a complete specification of data in a block.

Both these diagrams have misleading elements. For example the direction of arrows in the first diagram. The inclusion of "proof of work" in the second diagram as if that were a data item stored in the block structure. It isn't.

---

> Are transactions included in a block or is only the Merkle-root hash included in a block

The cause of this confusion is that

- The block hash includes the block header only†.
- The block data includes a block-header and *all* transaction data.

†The hash of the block does not *directly* include the transaction data. The transaction data is included *indirectly*.

One of the items in the block header is the Merkle root. The Merkle root is a hash resulting from repeated pairwise hashing of transaction data. A consequence of this is that altering any transaction *would* result in a different block hash.

---

See

- [Block structure](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#block)
- [Transaction structure](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#tx)
- [What are the components of the raw block shown in this image?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/114108/13866)
- [In what format does a block store the transaction data?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/113631/13866)

Comment: I believe the field "proof of work" referred to is actually the nonce; that is sometimes referred to as the proof.

Comment: @Pieter: In Picture-2, "proof of work" is pointed to by "previous block" in the next block and it starts with many zeroes. Aren't both rather suggestive of block hash?

Comment: Oh, yes, I guess that's an attempt at referring to the block hash. Strange that it's not hexadecimal though.

Answer (score 1):

Merkle tree root exists and is stored inside **Block header**.

Transactions are themselves the leafs of the merkle tree.

The merkle tree is used to attach Transactions to the **Block header**.

Therefore, in Bitcoin, **Block** is **Block header** and **Transactions**