# How to decipher Bitcoin Hex code?

Tags: blockchain

I have this hex code:

```
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
```

I can easily convert it using [this](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/decodetx/). But then I end up with this:

```
{
"addresses": [
    "bc1qwekdlsh7kck6au0g4wfrj0gzncr7x3s3tx00ms",
    "bc1qh95x77falnrwhehpyp2jclcgveapwywgwqqqzs",
    "bc1qxc9v2kyal5g3qy968u86tkk29sshg2cmtqxcv8",
    "bc1qt7hwj3633p555gvweh955uzt3c3njluh68krac"
],
"block_height": -1,
"block_index": -1,
"confirmations": 0,
"double_spend": false,
"fees": 5678,
"hash": "21777202a03e8b9e6e7cc84b08f1b10e0b01932eddf6132c91cb6eec555c7a45",
"inputs": [
    {
        "addresses": [
            "bc1qxc9v2kyal5g3qy968u86tkk29sshg2cmtqxcv8"
        ],
        "age": 741192,
        "output_index": 1,
        "output_value": 116001,
        "prev_hash": "03b89e96980571fa375b97e4931895f3620e235adfd61c1c3f261c56db3e4669",
        "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash",
        "sequence": 4294967293,
        "witness": [
            "304402200484ecf7d86e39028fa3d5ecf8275629f8d5294de8a554c79bbb953914c9edda022013b1f30577f18eb988ee6b7ec810201d34f555a5d7cb334479896d3692c4676101",
            "031f1ae8de454c0ce5a239cbef1559d5004740db4b664bd3ff0623fde49142ffd5"
        ]
    },
    {
        "addresses": [
            "bc1qt7hwj3633p555gvweh955uzt3c3njluh68krac"
        ],
        "age": 742121,
        "output_index": 3,
        "output_value": 500000,
        "prev_hash": "23b8460b3aa00a424608b9dd310965981b986aabe646a169769f4db312cff54a",
        "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash",
        "sequence": 4294967293,
        "witness": [
            "304402202d911869548104efcb3d9657fc82df41f99edd828fa34c62a6e3a5a6f53b0892022012946e4081250724616d424ea3c05684361d7973c86fc9417cda574d230ac2f801",
            "0288e0946ff5b1c8b4ae356203256ed7d92f07288f92b09b4a47fc22527d243ad1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "addresses": [
            "bc1qt7hwj3633p555gvweh955uzt3c3njluh68krac"
        ],
        "age": 742128,
        "output_index": 1,
        "output_value": 14248279,
        "prev_hash": "b76f8c74506f3c8d80f9bc86b5b7f4de9a42d4babb94668a2c666b56d0e50f81",
        "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash",
        "sequence": 4294967293,
        "witness": [
            "3044022022c894a0a2c1781a6db1043c52a90b519f6c2692aa983dc73c9bc07b514788170220375bfc525e20fd044c9da198abd88b6851fca39f74668e94047ce38c8fd30ee401",
            "0288e0946ff5b1c8b4ae356203256ed7d92f07288f92b09b4a47fc22527d243ad1"
        ]
    }
],
"lock_time": 742137,
"opt_in_rbf": true,
"outputs": [
    {
        "addresses": [
            "bc1qwekdlsh7kck6au0g4wfrj0gzncr7x3s3tx00ms"
        ],
        "script": "0014766cdfc2feb62daef1e8ab92393d029e07e34611",
        "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash",
        "value": 110323
    },
    {
        "addresses": [
            "bc1qh95x77falnrwhehpyp2jclcgveapwywgwqqqzs"
        ],
        "script": "0014b9686f793dfcc6ebe6e120552c7f08667a1711c8",
        "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash",
        "value": 14748279
    }
],
"preference": "low",
"received": "2022-06-29T02:42:35.768096075Z",
"relayed_by": "52.201.241.48",
"size": 518,
"total": 14858602,
"ver": 2,
"vin_sz": 3,
"vout_sz": 2,
"vsize": 276
```

}

My problem is understanding this second part. I know this transaction was for 0.14248279 BTC that was sent from address = bc1qt7hwj3633p555gvweh955uzt3c3njluh68krac. But my problems are:

1. I don't know how to calculate it based on the information above. Is there a guide that explains how to do it? What should I search for?
2. The Blockchain API is returning a different value for this transaction: https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/bc1qxc9v2kyal5g3qy968u86tkk29sshg2cmtqxcv8?limit-25 (look for "21777202a03e8b9e6e7cc84b08f1b10e0b01932eddf6132c91cb6eec555c7a45" and then you should see it's result value = -116001.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the parts of a Bitcoin transaction in segwit format?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/113697/what-are-the-parts-of-a-bitcoin-transaction-in-segwit-format)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, that all the values are written in Satoshis (1BTC = 100.000.000Sats). The value is in this line: `"value": 14748279` which is 14,748,279 Satoshis or 0.14748279 Bitcoin!