# Native P2WSH over P2SH | P2SH-P2WSH

Tags: python, p2sh, p2wsh

I'm in the process of attempting to generate a transaction using the [Python Bitcoin Utils library](https://github.com/karask/python-bitcoin-utils/tree/master). that involves P2WSH-over-P2SH (P2SH-P2WSH). My activity is on the regtest network. Below is the code snippet and address that I've prepared.

```python
txin_redeemScript = Script([
    'OP_2',
    private_key1.get_public_key().to_hex(),
    private_key2.get_public_key().to_hex(),
    'OP_2',
    'OP_CHECKMULTISIG'
])
script_bytes = txin_redeemScript.to_bytes()
hashsha256 = hashlib.sha256(script_bytes).digest()
hashsha256 = hexlify(hashsha256).decode('utf-8')

txin_scriptPubKey = Script(['OP_0', hashsha256])
txin_p2wsh_address = P2shAddress.from_script(txin_scriptPubKey)
```

This address is where I intend to send the coins, and this is the transaction I'm forming:

```python
p2pkh_addr = P2pkhAddress('n4bkvTyU1dVdzsrhWBqBw8fEMbHjJvtmJR')
txout = TxOutput(to_satoshis(amount_to_send), p2pkh_addr.to_script_pub_key())
tx = Transaction(inputs=p2sh_utxo, outputs=[txout], has_segwit=False)
```

This is the transaction and raw transaction ID

```
[{'address': '2N4vHiXTCCVMt4TYimTGXRCySzNLXkdiPyH', 'category': 'send', 'amount': Decimal('-0.10000000'), 'vout': 1, 'fee': Decimal('-0.00001430'), 'confirmations': 0, 'trusted': True, 'txid': 'f5f9c98b0c7b0731cba11f5a1b0494a62d2a2de5c09aaf3ac37fa56d48c271bd', 'wtxid': 'bed63897ca9c23ee891a9752b143ee063bf9aa97c813c5a455210a5f8437be6a', 'walletconflicts': [], 'time': 1693271904, 'timereceived': 1693271904, 'bip125-replaceable': 'yes', 'abandoned': False}]

0200000001bd71c2486da57fc33aaf9ac0e52d2a2da694041b5a1fa1cb31077b0c8bc9f9f50100000000ffffffff015f5d9800000000001976a914fd337ad3bf81e086d96a68e1f8d6a0a510f8c24a88ac00000000
```

The following code is utilized to sign the transaction:

```python
for tx_idx, txin in enumerate(p2sh_utxo):
    sig1 = sk1.sign_input(tx, tx_idx, txin_redeemScript)
    sig2 = sk2.sign_input(tx, tx_idx, txin_redeemScript)
    unlocking_script = Script(['OP_0', txin_redeemScript.to_hex()])
    txin.script_sig = unlocking_script

    witness_data = [b'','OP_0', sig1, sig2]
    tx.witnesses.append(TxWitnessInput(witness_data))
```

The mempool acceptance test is failing with the error  `'reject-reason': 'mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Script evaluated without error but finished with a false/empty top stack element)'}`

My familiarity with bitcoin programming is limited, and I've been unable to locate any sample code or references concerning P2WSH over P2SH. Despite searching various online resources, I have yet to find any explanations on how the spending process operates. Any help would be appreciated.

You can find the complete code [here](https://github.com/Deepanshu2017/bitcoingist/blob/main/P2SH-P2WSH.ipynb)

Comment: It is quite difficult to understand what is going on from the above. Are you certain that the funds are locked in the exact same output type that you are trying to spend? (p2sh(p2wsh(multi-sig) ) ) ?  If not, it will never work.

Comment: I noticed that in witness_data you add two values (instead of one for the multisig bug) before the signatures. Why?

Comment: Hello @karask thank you for the comment. I am trying to spend P2SH (P2WSH (Multi-sig) ). 
I tried so many things in the last couple of days that I have lost track. I tried only one value in the witness data before adding the signatures and hash however that was not working. 
I have tried to reach out to you over email as well (with the Jupyter notebook) however if you like (and if helps the community) I can attach Jupyter notebook here.

Comment: Hello @karask this is the Jupyter Nootebook attached on Github

https://github.com/Deepanshu2017/bitcoingist/blob/main/P2SH-P2WSH.ipynb

I have modified the question to attach the notebook URL

Comment: Hi @Deepanshu  I see in ipynb that you work in a regtest environment. So I assume you created this p2sh-p2wsh(multisig) yourself and are trying to spend it. In order for me to take a thorough look I would need the code for the creation of that UTXO first... and then the code for spending it (like the one your provided) but in testnet/signet so that I can test directly. Too many times, esp. in complex scenarios like this, the problem is that the UTXO is not what you thought it was...

Comment: Hello @karask 
Thank you for the response. I generated two private keys using some libraries and then using the keys to p2wsh witness script followed by p2sh address. This is the address that got generated "2N4vHiXTCCVMt4TYimTGXRCySzNLXkdiPyH". (Cell number 3 in Jupyter notebook) After this, I created a transaction using bitcoin cli. `bitcoin-cli -regtest sendtoaddress "2N4vHiXTCCVMt4TYimTGXRCySzNLXkdiPyH" 0.1` 
Post this starting from cell number 5 in the notebook, I am trying to spend this. The choice of env (regtest/test) doesn't matter in my case. All I am trying to do is P2WSH in P2SH

Comment: Essentially P2WSH is supposed to be backward compatible with P2SH and that's what I am trying to demonstrate with Python Code. We have the deadline to submit the paper tomorrow and if we could somehow make it work, it would be useful addition in our paper.

Comment: I don't have time to test it right now. Going though the code I noticed that you sign with sign_input but you should use sign_segwit_input. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello @karask thank you so much for the comment, however changing the sign to `sign_segwit_input` did not help.
Thank you for the help. Whenever you have time, you can fix the issue, this may help the community to have some sort of reference and would help me as well to eventually figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construction of transaction to send to a P2SH(P2WSH) UTXO follows:

```
from bitcoinutils.keys import P2shAddress, PrivateKey
from bitcoinutils.script import Script
from bitcoinutils.setup import setup
from bitcoinutils.hdwallet import HDWallet
from bitcoinutils.transactions import Transaction, TxInput, TxOutput

setup("testnet")

#
# Send from a P2PKH UTXO and send to P2SH(P2WSH(P2PK))
# Change back to the same address (not recommended for privacy reasons)
#

xprivkey = (
    "tprv8ZgxMBicQKsPdQR9RuHpGGxSnNq8Jr3X4WnT6Nf2eq7FajuXyBep5KWYpYEixxx5XdTm1N"
    "tpe84f3cVcF7mZZ7mPkntaFXLGJD2tS7YJkWU"
)
path = "m/86'/1'/0'/0/1"
hdw = HDWallet(xprivkey, path)
from_priv = hdw.get_private_key()
from_pub = from_priv.get_public_key()
from_addr = from_pub.get_address()
print("From address:", from_addr.to_string())

hdw.from_path("m/86'/1'/0'/0/20")
to_priv = hdw.get_private_key()
to_pub = to_priv.get_public_key()

witness_script = Script([to_pub.to_hex(), "OP_CHECKSIG"])
p2sh_redeem_script = witness_script.to_p2wsh_script_pub_key()  # maybe to_p2sh_...

p2sh_address = P2shAddress.from_script(p2sh_redeem_script)
print("To address:", p2sh_address.to_string())

# UTXO's info
txid = "d4616b3050d2a0fac4783cd9a8c727aafa7b1374098d049e91ecc66d655e79e7"
vout = 0

txin = TxInput(txid, vout)
txout = TxOutput(5000, p2sh_redeem_script.to_p2sh_script_pub_key())
txout_change = TxOutput(1530000, from_addr.to_script_pub_key())
tx = Transaction([txin], [txout, txout_change])

sig = from_priv.sign_input(tx, 0, from_addr.to_script_pub_key())

txin.script_sig = Script([sig, from_pub.to_hex()])

signed_tx = tx.serialize()

print(signed_tx)
```

Construction of transaction to spend from a P2SH(P2WSH) UTXO follows:

```
from bitcoinutils.keys import P2shAddress, PrivateKey
from bitcoinutils.script import Script
from bitcoinutils.setup import setup
from bitcoinutils.hdwallet import HDWallet
from bitcoinutils.transactions import Transaction, TxInput, TxOutput, TxWitnessInput

setup("testnet")

#
# Send from a P2SH(P2WSH(P2PK)) UTXO to a P2PKH UTXO
#

xprivkey = (
    "tprv8ZgxMBicQKsPdQR9RuHpGGxSnNq8Jr3X4WnT6Nf2eq7FajuXyBep5KWYpYEixxx5XdTm1N"
    "tpe84f3cVcF7mZZ7mPkntaFXLGJD2tS7YJkWU"
)
path = "m/86'/1'/0'/0/20"
hdw = HDWallet(xprivkey, path)
from_priv = hdw.get_private_key()
print(from_priv.to_wif())
from_pub = from_priv.get_public_key()
from_addr = from_pub.get_address()

witness_script = Script([from_pub.to_hex(), "OP_CHECKSIG"])
p2sh_redeem_script = witness_script.to_p2wsh_script_pub_key()
print("From address:", P2shAddress.from_script(p2sh_redeem_script).to_string())

hdw.from_path("m/86'/1'/0'/0/25")
to_priv = hdw.get_private_key()
to_address = to_priv.get_public_key().get_address()
print("To address:", to_address.to_string())

# UTXO's info
txid = "217f123726bd8ace101afd705ae31384fd818fce17c8e00ce6fc0d24c0364355"
vout = 0
amount = 5000

txin = TxInput(txid, vout)
txout = TxOutput(3000, to_address.to_script_pub_key())
tx = Transaction([txin], [txout], has_segwit=True)

sig = from_priv.sign_segwit_input(tx, 0, witness_script, amount)

txin.script_sig = Script([p2sh_redeem_script.to_hex()])
tx.witnesses.append(TxWitnessInput([sig, witness_script.to_hex()]))

signed_tx = tx.serialize()

print(signed_tx)
```

See also:
https://github.com/karask/python-bitcoin-utils/blob/master/examples/send_to_p2sh_p2wsh_p2pk_address.py

and

https://github.com/karask/python-bitcoin-utils/blob/master/examples/spend_from_p2sh_p2wsh_p2pk_address.py

Comment: I want to express my gratitude for providing the examples, but it seems they aren't functioning correctly.

I attempted to perform a transaction from a `P2SH(P2WSH(P2PK)) to P2PKH`, and it resulted in an error `bad-witness-nonstandard.`

To investigate further, I decided to verify the UTXOs mentioned in the code on Bitcoin Explorer. Unfortunately, I couldn't locate these UTXOs on Bitcoin Explorer.

The specific UTXO in question is 
 `217f123726bd8ace101afd705ae31384fd818fce17c8e00ce6fc0d24c0364355` 

https://github.com/Deepanshu2017/bitcoingist/blob/main/P2SH-P2WSH%20Ka.ipynb

Comment: I would like to point out 1 thing though, the way I am creating transaction (to get the transaction id for code in regtest) is by passing the `to address` in `sendtoaddress` command

`./bitcoin-cli -regtest sendtoaddress "mhZ7PvZZp5dafdGdds37m5AbZzArtqFsgT" 0.1`

After running the above command, I am getting the transaction id which I have used in code. This is the only command that I am running on bitcoin cli.

My regtest Private Keys are correct (hence the address generated must be correct) however there could be an issue with the way I am generating the transaction.

Comment: I have tried these transactions as well
https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/tx/3fc77c60aab834c83f88e041c399ccefbb1938ec25eaf9914b6fcf775996bf1d/

However I can replicate the error while pushing to blockstream

https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/push

Comment: You cannot see the transactions with a testnet explorer because I have not broadcasted them. I am testing them with my local node with testmempoolaccept. This way I don't need to be sending funds back and forth all the time for the tests.

Comment: Just to be certain try the examples directly from the github repo (don't copy/paste from here). I just tried the examples and they worked. You can try them yourself, even with regtest by directly running them and then do a: bitcoin-cli testmempoolaccept ["first tx raw hex", "second tx raw hex"]    (this way you also test the 2nd tx that depends on the first without broadcasting them)

Comment: By directly running them I mean your either use your own keys instead of the ones I used in the example or you need to import the keys in the example to your bitcoin node. Not sure which one you tried. I am also not sure if you got the above error running the two examples I provided or by trying to fix your code.

Comment: Hi @karask,

Thank you so much for the response. I tried running the example from GitHub, cloned the repo, ran both the examples and did mempool accept test by providing both the hex. It worked. I tried individual hex as well and it worked.
Thank you so much.

One last question, When I tried running it from Notebook it failed. Let me try again.

https://github.com/Deepanshu2017/bitcoingist/blob/main/P2SH-P2WSH%20Ka.ipynb

Again thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. I would suggest compare the raw hex of the txs to see how they differ to pinpoint what changes. You will need to get acquainted with the structure of the bitcoin transaction to do that properly. e.g. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/113697/what-are-the-parts-of-a-bitcoin-transaction-in-segwit-format

Comment: Okay so the error must be either the way I am creating transaction or Private Key.
To generate Private Key I have used `PrivateKey` class from `bitcoinutils.keys`

To generate the transaction, I copied the from address (which was in this case `2MuxtgnkyrUSudv99YbeApZQtfQmtuw7e8p` ), went to https://coinfaucet.eu/en/btc-testnet/ and sent some funds. That gave me the transaction ID which I am using in the code.

Comment: This is the notebook, that is the same code as yours however uses the different Private Key.
https://github.com/Deepanshu2017/bitcoingist/blob/main/P2WSH%20Ka.ipynb

Basic trimmed down version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148483/discussion-between-karask-and-deepanshu).