# How to compute a TXID of any bitcoin transaction in Python

Tags: python, transaction-id

there, I've already looked at other similar posts on here but with little luck. All im trying to do is calculate the TXID of a transaction after downloading the transaction in hexadecimal from a blockchain explorer VIA an API.

The problem is that the TXID calculated Isn't the TXID we expect.

Here's the code, I'm using bitcoin-utils

```
from bitcoinutils.transactions import Transaction
import requests


# Fetch the raw transaction data from the blockchain.info API
tx_hash = '9d2d91b764ba2559b098cdd30525e2160bb15c6e27d6869e7b121a9037d8bd86'
api_response = requests.get(f'https://blockchain.info/rawtx/{tx_hash}?format=hex')

if api_response.status_code == 200:
    raw_tx_hex = str(api_response.text)
else:
    print(f"Error fetching transaction data: {api_response.status_code}")


mytrans = Transaction.from_raw(raw_tx_hex)
print(mytrans.get_txid())
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a SegWit transaction, not all of it is part of the transaction hash preimage (see [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/113697/what-are-the-parts-of-a-bitcoin-transaction-in-segwit-format) for details). You have to exclude the SegWit parts. This Bash one-liner returns the correct TXID:

```
echo '0100000001189a3f6fbfb614264c8176cd2d3836882afc3c0940d698d6b481f3e5cb733c200000000000ffffffff0240420f00000000001976a914341b568f59229818c460b1795ad48cd78895c54d88ac6eeefa4a00000000160014d701ce5e753bd9454d343c8a3b86d84a3c34dbf500000000' | tr -d '\n' | xxd -r -p | sha256sum | grep -oE '^[0-9a-f]+' | xxd -r -p | sha256sum | grep -oE '^[0-9a-f]+' | tac -rs '..'; echo
```

Output

`9d2d91b764ba2559b098cdd30525e2160bb15c6e27d6869e7b121a9037d8bd86`

#### Explanation

Your TX can be disassembled as follows, and you have to hash everything **except the bold parts**:

TX version: `01000000`
**Witness marker and flag: `0001`**
Input count: `01`
Prevout reference: `189a3f6fbfb614264c8176cd2d3836882afc3c0940d698d6b481f3e5cb733c2000000000`
Unlocking script length: `00`
*Unlocking script: EMPTY* (note: non-SegWit inputs will have script length >0 and have the unlocking script here instead of in the witness, so for non-SegWit this will not be EMPTY)
Sequence: `ffffffff`
Output count: `02`
Output 01: `40420f00000000001976a914341b568f59229818c460b1795ad48cd78895c54d88ac`
Output 02: `6eeefa4a00000000160014d701ce5e753bd9454d343c8a3b86d84a3c34dbf5`
**Witness count: `02`**
**Witness 01: `473044022001609cd43eb8e9b8f8438eded9f6b10bad32efd7620724ccd2ed5277c0c6a3ae02200f0c1c3f4c409ada536d2363a2d8bdad418df67fed9b36bfa4482bd9985bf39601`**
**Witness 02: `2102ee3c98964dd1bfe13bee16c0b95fcf8281f12c5885d1fcb7b59fc2cb01ca7632`**
TX locktime: `00000000`

Concatenating only the non-SegWit parts gives us the TX hash preimage: `0100000001189a3f6fbfb614264c8176cd2d3836882afc3c0940d698d6b481f3e5cb733c200000000000ffffffff0240420f00000000001976a914341b568f59229818c460b1795ad48cd78895c54d88ac6eeefa4a00000000160014d701ce5e753bd9454d343c8a3b86d84a3c34dbf500000000`

Comment: Thank you bca-0353f40e for you answer, would you be able to edit my python code so that all is needed from the user is the TXID? Thanks

Comment: That's too much work for me. You can figure it out, just parse the transaction according to format specification and skip over SegWit parts.

Comment: Do you know of any API's which will return a TX hash preimage, from a TXID?

Comment: Don't know, but maybe you can look for a library. I found PyPI which implements "tx_hash : (hex or bin tx) -> hash" https://pypi.org/project/pycryptotools/0.2.1/

Comment: Source seems to have been deleted, here's a mirror: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5445428.0

Link to tx_hash implementation: https://github.com/ZenulAbidin/pycryptotools/blob/main/pycryptotools/transaction.py#L278